# Basic Property of Normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory

For a subgroup $N$ of $G$, if the **product of two right cosets** of $N$ in $G$ is again **right coset** of $N$ in $G$,
then $N$ is normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: i have proved converse of this statement, which i find very easy. but this proof require some trick.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say $aNbN = acN$. Then $Nb = cN$. Write $n_1b = cn_2$ for any $ n_1$ and some $n_2$ in $N$. Take $n_1 = e$ to get $b = cn_2$. Take $n_2 = e$ to get $b = n_1^{-1}c$. Put them together for $cn_2 = n_1^{-1}c$. This is equivalent to $cN = Nc$ and makes $N$ normal.

Comment: Thanks.This is very helpful.

Comment: it may be my lack of understanding, but please tell me how you conclude, from aNbN = acN to Nb = cN.

Comment: $aNbN = acN$ means that $an_1bn_2 = acn_3$ for any $n_1$, $n_2$ and some $n_3$ in $N$. From that we get $n_1b = cn_3n_2^{-1}$ for any $n_1$ and some $n_3n_2^{-1}$.